# Is it necessary to create a self signed cert for Nginx under ACM on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy on an EC2 in the private subnet. In the public subnet, I created an ALB and also created an ACM for domain `proxy.mydomain.test`.

The LB's target group is using 443 port with HTTPS protocol. The LB's listener is also using the 443 port and HTTPS protocol, even `ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08` ssl policy and ACM's certificate arn. It's action is using `forward`.

The LB's listener rule's action is also `forward` with `host_header` condition. Its value is the full domain `proxy.mydomain.test`.

The Nginx proxy server's duty is to point to the ELB endpoint in the internal subnet which serving an another service. So it maybe should use [proxy_pass](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-for-devops/blob/master/https-nginx-proxy/provisioning/templates/https.test.conf.j2#L18), then I think the [/var/www/html](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-for-devops/blob/master/https-nginx-proxy/provisioning/vars/main.yml#L15) isn't necessary.

So about the Nginx in the EC2, is it necesary to create a [self signed cert](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-for-devops/blob/master/https-nginx-proxy/provisioning/tasks/self-signed-cert.yml)?

And, in the [server listen config](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-for-devops/blob/master/https-nginx-proxy/provisioning/templates/https.test.conf.j2) of Nginx, use 80 or 443 to catch the inbound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't need SSL/HTTPS between ALB and instances, or when you route traffic within a VPC. So your traffic would be:

```
client ---(HTTPS)--->ALB----(HTTP)--->NGINX---(HTTP)--->ALB
```

Usually you only encrypt traffic from the internet to ALB.

Comment: So can I use [80](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-for-devops/blob/master/https-nginx-proxy/provisioning/templates/https.test.conf.j2#L5) only for server listen? Also set [proxy_pass](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-for-devops/blob/master/https-nginx-proxy/provisioning/templates/https.test.conf.j2#L18) in the 80 block?

Comment: @Miantian Yes. For HTTP port 80 is used. But on your first ALB, you need 443 for HTTPS, and probably set redirection from 80 to 443.

Answer (score 4):

This is up to your architecture.

- If your `NGINX proxy` is the public endpoint, it must have SSL
  certificate.
- If your `Load Balancer` is the public endpoint, it must
  have SSL certificate.

At this case, your `Load Balancer` is *internal* config which only allows *internal VPC access* so HTTP traffic (over port 80) is enough. But for best practices, you can enhance security at any layers and make them HTTPS which is encouraged.

For security reasons, for the public endpoint, we usually configure to *redirect traffic from port 80 to port 443*.

Reference: https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx/

Comment: My `NGINX proxy` is in the private subnet but the domain from ALB is public to internet. My `Load Balancer`, do you mean ALB? Yes, it's in the public subnet. But the Nginx will point to an another LB in the internal endpoint.

Comment: It is totally up to you to decide whether or not you will encrypt traffic between the ELB and your web server. It depends on whether you want to or need to encrypt end to end (e.g. in case you need to comply with a security standard). In the last few years it is considered to be a best practice. As Werner Vogels, CTO of Amazon likes to say: "Encrypt everything".